# cp hidden files with glob patterns

Tags: zsh, wildcards, cp, dot-files

Situation :

```
$ mkdir foo && touch foo/.test
$ cp foo/* .
zsh: no matches found: foo/*
(or bash : cp: cannot stat ‘foo/*’: No such file or directory)
```

I have a directory full of hidden folders and files. What is happening and what is the solution?

Comment: `dotglob` is translated to `globdots` by [tag:zsh] which is invalid option name for [tag:bash].

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer deals with Bash specifically but much of it applies to the question regarding glob patterns!*

The star character (`*`) is a wildcard. There are a certain set of characters that it will take the place of and the first character being a dot (`.`) isn't one of them. This is a special case just because of how the Unix filesystems work, files that start with a dot are considered "hidden". That means that tools such as `cp`, `ls`, etc. will not "see" them unless explicitly told to do so.

#### Examples

First let's create some sample data.

```
$ mkdir .dotdir{1,2} regdir{1,2}
$ touch .dotfile{1,2} regfile{1..3}
```

So now we have the following:

```
$ tree -a
.
|-- .dotdir1
|-- .dotdir2
|-- .dotfile1
|-- .dotfile2
|-- regdir1
|-- regdir2
|-- regfile1
|-- regfile2
`-- regfile3
```

Now let's play some games. You can use the command `echo` to list out what a particular wildcard (`*`) would be for a given command like so:

```
$ echo *
regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3


$ echo reg*
regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3

$ echo .*
. .. .dotdir1 .dotdir2 .dotfile1 .dotfile2

$ echo .* *
. .. .dotdir1 .dotdir2 .dotfile1 .dotfile2 regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3

$ echo .dotdir*
.dotdir1 .dotdir2
```

#### Changing the behavior?

You can use the command `shopt -s dotglob` to change the behavior of the `*` so that in addition to files like `regfile1` it will also match `.dotfile1`.

*excerpt from the `bash` man page*

```
dotglob If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results 
        of pathname expansion.
```

Example:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
.dotdir1 .dotdir2 .dotfile1 .dotfile2 regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3
```

You can revert this behavior with this command:

```
$ shopt -u dotglob
$ echo *
regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3
```

#### Your situation?

For you you're telling `cp` that you want to copy all the files that match the pattern `*`, and there aren't any files.

```
$ cp foo/.* .
```

Or you can do this if you want everything in the `foo` folder:

```
$ cp foo .
```

Or you can be explicit:

```
$ cp foot/.* foo/* .
```

A more compact form using brace expansion in `bash`:

```
$ cp foo/{.,}* .
```

At any time you can use the `echo` trick to see what your proposed file patterns (that's the fancy term for what the star is a part of).

```
$ echo {.,}*
. .. .dotdir1 .dotdir2 .dotfile1 .dotfile2 abc regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3
```

Incidentally if you're going to copy a directory of files + other directories, you typically want to do this recursively, that's the `-R` switch to `cp`:

```
$ cp -R foo/. .
```

Comment: You might want to mention the use of `shopt -s dotglob`, `echo *` then gives: `.dotdir1 .dotdir2 .dotfile1 .dotfile2 regdir1 regdir2 regfile1 regfile2 regfile3`

Comment: @DravSloan - thanks for the suggestion. Added it.

Comment: `cp -r foo .` will typically not work since `cp` will refuse to copy `foo` over itself, you probably meant `cp -R foo/. .`. (note that `cp -R` is the standard one).

Comment: Also note that (quite sensibly), `zsh` doesn't include `.` and `..` in the expansion of `.*`. In `zsh`, if a pattern doesn't match, the command is aborted (quite sensibly again), so in the general case, `cp foo/{,.}* .` will fail if there's no hidden or no non-hidden files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for keeping me honest. Fixed suggestions. Also from the `cp` man page it shows this: `-R, -r, --recursive`. I would take that to mean that any form of the switch is acceptable.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yeah I never could get used to `zsh`, still prefer `bash` even with all its warts.

Comment: You're reading the man page of GNU `cp`. GNU stands for `GNU's Not Unix`. Here, we're on `Unix and Linux`, `Unix` being in the largest sense of the word a family of operating systems and Linux the kernel found in a number of Unix-like operating systems. As such, GNU `cp` is just one of many implementations of the standard Unix `cp` command. The specification of the standard `cp` can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I figured that was the case. I understand we're on U&L, and appreciate your attention to the subtle differences (it's always an education on the finer points in both reading and chatting with you), but does it not seem to be a safe assumption? Or is your comment meant more to educate me and also passerby's, or a little of both? 8-)

Comment: This answer applies to bash only. The asker is using zsh, where the answer is [a lot simpler](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89749/cp-hidden-files-with-glob-patterns/89771#89771) and `shopt` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Gilles - I added a note at the top mentioned that this was Bash specific. Also the link in referenced didn't appear to work, it took me back to this question.

Comment: The link is to Stephane's answer.

Comment: @Gilles - weird when I clicked on it it jumps to the top of the Q. I figured that was what you were linking to.

Comment: The special meaning of a leading `.` meaning hidden files has nothing to do with _Unix file systems_. That's just a convention in applications.

Answer (score 48):

With `zsh`, the typical way is to use the `D` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (to include [D]ot files):

```
cp foo/*(D) .
```

Note that with or without `D`, zsh globs never include `.` nor `..` (as you'd expect).

Answer (score 4):

The shell is treating those files as hidden when it resolves the `*` character, so `cp` doesn't receive any of these file names as arguments.

You can copy them by explicitly specifying `cp foo/.* .`

Answer (score 4):

Stéphane Chazelas's zsh [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89771/18887) is correct for a single expression with a glob in it. However, if you want to set it for all expressions by default, you can use

```
setopt GLOB_DOTS
```

Put it in your `~/.zshrc` to make it permanent.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're wanting to do is copy all files & directories from one place to another, you could use the standard `rsync` command. In the example you give above:

```
mkdir foo && touch foo/.test
rsync -a foo/ .
```

will recursively copy all of the contents of `foo`, including hidden files and hidden directories, into the current directory. The trailing slash at the end of `foo/` is important to rsync; with it only the contents of `foo` are copied, without it rsync will copy `foo` as well. For example:-

```
mkdir src && mkdir dest && touch src/.test
rsync -a src  dest    // copies 'src' contents to 'dest/src'
rsync -a src/ dest    // copies 'src' contents to 'dest'
```

There are many other options available tweak rsync, including copying between machines.