# Shell-independent way to cp dotfiles from a folder to another

Tags: shell, cp, posix, dot-files

I have two existing directories :

- foo: directory with dotfiles in it
- foo2: empty directory

I would like to have a solution to copy all dotfiles in `foo` to foo2. I would like a solution that is not shell-dependent (bash, zsh, etc.). I would prefer not having to install `rsync` to do it (`tar` is ok).

Weeks ago, I asked [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89749/cp-hidden-files-with-glob-patterns), but I feel both questions should be separated as they answer different needs. All answers were shell-dependent or using `rsync`.

Comment: What's wrong with `cp -r foo/.??* foo2/`?

Comment: Beat me to it Joseph, was going to say the same. Dropping the `-r` option will only copy files as directories will give the `cp: omitting directory` error.

Comment: @JosephR. Why do you add `??`?

Comment: @Gradient To ensure the files/directories that match have at least 3 characters so you avoid matching `.` and `..` which would be... unpleasant.

Comment: @JosephR. Is it standard on all shells?

Comment: @Gradient: here is a portable solution, avoiding duplicates (as in chosen answer) : `for i in foo/.* ; do [ "$i" = "foo/." ] && continue ; [ "$i" = "foo/.." ] && continue ; cp -r "$i" foo2 ; done`  (ie, list all .* and avoid "." and ".." only). It does copy file and/or directories as well. If you want only files, replace it by: `for i in foo/.* ; do [ ! -f "$i" ] && { echo "skipping: $i" ;  continue ; } ; cp -r "$i" foo2 ; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "shell independent", you are restricting yourself to Bourne-type shells (not csh, etc)

```
cp -r foo/.??* foo/.[^.] foo2
```

Comment: Note that it is not shell independant since `[^.]` is not Bourne nor POSIX (though is `csh`, `[!.]` is the POSIX one). Also, `-r` is not portable. Also in `zsh`, if either of those patterns doesn't match any file, an error will be reported and the command will not be run. Also a file called `.[^.]` may be copied twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy everything, including dotfiles:

```
cp -a src/. dest
```